# Shunting-yard Algorithm

Tags: clojure, shunting-yard

I'm working on implementing an infix-calculator in Clojure, which starts with me implementing Dijkstra's Shunting-yard Algorithm. I thought I had it down pretty well, but joke's on me, it doesn't seem to handle operators very well at all. Calling `(shunting-yard "3 + 5")` `=>` `(\3)`. That's all. Could someone tell me what's wrong with my handling of operator characters here?

```
(import '(java.lang.Character))

(defn operator? [sym]
  "Determines if a given token is a mathematical operator."
  (some #{sym} '(\+ \- \* \/ \% \^ \!)))

(defn associativity-of [operator]
  "Determines the associativity of a given mathematical operator."
  (if (some #{operator} '(\+ \- \* \/ \%))
    'left
    'right))

(defn precedence-of [operator]
  "Determines the precedence of a given mathematical operator."
  (case operator
        (\+ \-)    2
        (\* \/ \%) 3
        (\^ \!)    4
                   0))

(defn operator-actions [stmt stack]
  "Actions taken when the next token in the stmt is an operator."
  (let [token-prec  (precedence-of (first stmt))
        token-assoc (associativity-of (first stmt))
        stack-oper  (first stack)
        stack-prec  (precedence-of stack-oper)]
    (cond (or (and (= token-assoc 'left)
                   (<= token-prec stack-prec))
              (and (= token-assoc 'right)
                   (< token-prec stack-prec)))
          (cons stack-oper (shunt stmt (rest stack)))
          :else (shunt (rest stmt) (cons (first stmt) stack)))))

(defn stack-operations [stack]
  "Actions to take if (nil? stmt)"
  (comment "If a left paren is found on the stack, it means
           that there was no right paren to match it, and
           therefore the statement had unbalanced parentheses.")
  (cond (and (not (nil? stack))
             (= (first stack) \()) (print "Unbalanced parentheses.\n")
        (nil? stack) ()
        :else (cons (first stack) (stack-operations (rest stack)))))

(defn shunt [stmt stack]
  (cond (empty? stmt) (stack-operations stack)
        (Character/isDigit (first stmt)) (cons (first stmt)
                                               (shunt (rest stmt) stack))
        (operator? (first stmt)) (operator-actions stmt stack)
        (= (first stmt) \() (recur (rest stmt) (cons (first stmt) stack))
        (= (first stmt) \)) (if (= (first stack) \()
                              (recur (rest stmt) (rest stack))
                              (cons (first stack) (shunt stmt (rest stack))))))

(defn shunting-yard [stmt]
  (shunt stmt ()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actually know the Shunting-Yard algorithm (save 2 minutes in Wikipedia just now), but one issue I see is that that `shunt` doesn't handle spaces.  So it reads your `\3`, recurses, and exits since the next char is `\space`.  If `stmt` has no spaces, i.e. `"3+5"`, you get a `StackOverflowError`, but that's progress, I guess.

Comment: Great, thank you. Adding a simple `:else (shunt (rest stmt) stack)` to the `cond` took care of that. Now I just have to figure out that stack overflow.

Comment: Cool.  Good luck with the algorithm.